# Single channel vs Multiple channel-Hyperledger fabric supply chain

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, channel

For a hyperledger fabric based **supply chain** ,which is better and why?
Single channel or multiple channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the use case you are trying to implement. If there is need for confidential transaction/ledger for some organizations in the n/w, separate channel will be required. You may also consider private data collection if the same ledger have to be used among participants, but some transaction data have to be kept confidential among them.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/private-data/private-data.html#when-to-use-a-collection-within-a-channel-vs-a-separate-channel

Answer (score 1):

I won't restrict it to single channel. One channel with all the stakeholders would be needed so that provenance can be tracked. Certain states could be kept on that common channel so that it is visible to all parties and so that basic operations and provenance can be handled.

Wherever the data access has to be restricted, you could use private data collections (PDCs) so that there could be more control on privacy. You could have even smaller channels to handle the smaller, business level group level functionalities, but not too many of them as each channel adds on the load of a separate "logical" datastore (not physical).